# How should filtering product-objects be approached?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently doing a project in ASP.NET Core MVC that is going to involve filtering of items on a sort of "store" page.
My issue is that there are going to be multiple types of products, which I represent by having an abstract class called `Product` with common properties, which will be used to derive from for the actual product classes.
Here's an example of code to show what I mean:

`Product.cs`:

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductA.cs`:

```cs
public class ProductA : Product
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductB.cs`:

```cs
public class ProductB : Product
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that I wanted to filter all products on the `Weight` property in either an `IEnumerable<Product>` or `IQueryable<Product>`, how would I do that without getting runtime errors due to some objects not defining the property?
I'm aware that I could use reflection, but I know that's very slow, so I'm assuming there is a better way, or an entirely different approach from mine.

I have considered whether I should simply be testing for the type of object when handling any object that derives from `Product`, but this seems very hard to maintain since any new product would add a new `if` anywhere a product is being processed.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `Weight` doesn't exist in Product, so Product has no idea what Weight is. Can you not add Weight to Product?

Comment: @gunr2171 i could, but not every product will define `Weight`, which is why it doesn't make sense to me it should be in the base class.

Comment: If you want to manage without If's then you definitely have to check for whether the `Weight` property belongs to the object or not and for that you know it's reflection.
Abstract class inheritance advantages are in case of overriden or overloaded methods.

Comment: @Mantra so it's essentially a tradeoff between speed and how dynamic the implementation is? Is there any alternatives that would work better than properties with `if`s or reflection?
I'm not sure if i'm taking the wrong approach, or if it's just a trade-off that has to be made.

Comment: @MrMeatballGuy Where is all this data coming from? If this is coming from an external database (especially a relational database) then you're wasting your time because all of this will be handled by your database code, which is often just SQL (and sparse-tables) and _not_ by in-memory C# objects. I'm not a fan of undergrad coursework that represents business/domain entities as OOP classes because (generally speaking) data-modelling always tends to happen in the database and in service boundaries (e.g. DTOs, etc) - and never inside a monolithic in-memory process (Smalltalk had its chance...).

Comment: @Dai it is indeed coming from a relational database, but it's based on Entity Framework which forces me to filter on the actual properties of objects as far as i can tell.

Comment: @MrMeatballGuy Yes, Indeed; the tradeoff will be there.
Considering the dynamic nature of your product that will only be known at the runtime while you are creating the object of that product and assigning to object of parent class Product. There is no way for CLR to know class of object and if that specific property on which you want to filter on is present in that newly assigned product object.
Unless you specifically ask the CLR to look for it's properties.
And you know the moment you ask for properties of object in memory you will have to reflect on class of which this object is.

Comment: @MrMeatballGuy Entity Framework really _does not_ work well with custom type hierarchies. However you are incorrect to say "but it's based on Entity Framework **which forces me to filter on the actual properties** of objects as far as i can tell" - because you can still use raw SQL with EF. You also can't use custom/computed properties in a Linq-to-SQL expression: only mapped properties.

Comment: @MrMeatballGuy What you probably should be using is a [Sparse Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) (instead of the EAV anti-pattern) with some dynamic query builder (which you'll probably need to write yourself) - Entity Framework won't help you _at all_ for scenarios like this (especially as Entity Framework doesn't support sparse tables anyway).